# Setup Events between MEF Exports and Host

Tags: mef

I am new to MEF (been playing around with it for a few weeks now).

Here is what I have built - I have a host (Console App) that is loading up all my exports (I have 3 different exports as separate dlls).  This works really well.  Note these exports are all separate class libraries, even my host loader is only a windows console application.

The export libraries each handle different data providers.

What I would like to do is extend my main interface to have an event on it so that the exports can notify the host when their data has changed and let the host notify the rest of the application (not MEF) accordingly.

I'm having some trouble trying to find the proper pattern to wire up events between the exports and the host.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just hook up the event handler where you import your data providers?

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IDataProvider))]
public IEnumerable<IDataProvider> DataProviders
{
   private get
   {
      return this.dataProviders;
   }
   set
   {
      this.dataProviders = value;
      foreach (var dataProvider in value)
      {
          dataProvider.DataChanged += HandleDataChanged;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to add an eventhandler onto the interface that my exports are using?  I did try this, consumed it all fine, but then started receiving a ReflectionTypeLoadException.  I noticed that there was no difference between having a generic EventArgs or custom in the event handler.

Comment: @GT.: The `ReflectionTypeLoadException` is a separate problem, one typically caused by defunct assemblies lying around in your build folder. They are still picked up by a MEF `DirectoryCatalog`. When MEF tries to load those assemblies, it fails when they reference types that no longer exist.

Comment: I can't get this solution to work. Could you provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

If your data are files in a folder, you can try with [Events of FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx#eventTableToggle) in order to detect changes in these files.